# ContentResolver.getPackageName()' on a null object reference when calling an intent

Tags: android

The following is the exception I get :-

```
07-29 15:56:57.647 7358-7358/org.blueshireservices.wallace D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-29 15:56:57.648 7358-7358/org.blueshireservices.wallace E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: org.blueshireservices.wallace, PID: 7358
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.blueshireservices.wallace/org.blueshireservices.wallace.SiteMaps}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.ContentResolver.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.ContentResolver.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
        at android.provider.Settings$NameValueCache.getStringForUser(Settings.java:1767)
        at android.provider.Settings$Global.getStringForUser(Settings.java:13773)
        at android.provider.Settings$Global.getString(Settings.java:13762)
        at android.provider.Settings$Global.getInt(Settings.java:13829)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.<init>(PhoneWindow.java:356)
        at android.app.Activity.attach(Activity.java:6882)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2861)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

The code is as follows:-

```
private void callSiteMap() {
    Log.d(TAG, "callSiteMap ");

    MyImageMap.setScreenData(DataContentProvider.P_MAIN_IMAGE);

    Log.d(TAG, "callSiteMap 2 ");
    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Easy, 10 selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SiteMaps.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private void displayLog() {
    // Log.d(TAG, "displayLog--");
    Intent intent = new Intent( MainActivity.this , MainLog.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The strange thing is that when I run the program and call the program SiteMaps straight away I receive the nullpointerexception. When I call the MainLog program and then return and then call the SiteMaps program there is no exception.

[The program structure is as shown in the picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tubr.jpg)

I have been investigating this for over a week. I have looked at all the similiar issues on stackoverflow and they do not seem to apply. This is not a fragment.
It is very puzzling.

Comment: The problem is in `SiteMaps`, but I can't quite figure out a way it could crash to get that stack trace. Please post the `SiteMaps` class.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to navigate from an activity to another activity but instead of passing your current activity to the intent you are passing the application context in

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SiteMaps.class);
```

The current view of your application is not directly known from the application context, which is why you get null exception. Change it to

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SiteMaps.class);
```

And it should work.

Comment: The "getApplicationContext()" was a result of reading previous entries in StackOverflow. I was trying this option to see if it changed anything. Originally the statement was as follows:-

Comment: The "getApplicationContext()" was a result of reading previous entries in StackOverflow. I was trying this option to see if it changed anything. Originally the statement was as follows:-  Intent intent = new intent(MainActivity.this, SiteMaps.class); The same as the MainLog call method below. I did modify the intent back to the original subsequent to your email and it exited in exactly the same manner.